# How to create and set roles in Oracle by Oracle Sql Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a Oracle SQL Developer and I want to create and set multiple roles for a specified table (e.g. for insert, update, delete and select statements), but when I use either Grant or Revoke Statements to do these,  like this:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE on Employees to username or rolename
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE on Employees from username or rolename
```

results do not appear and so I cant use insert, update, select statement in Oracle and I try to issue these statements again and again but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to grand these privileges to a user, you have to connect with a user that has the privileges to do so.

If you are connected with such a user you can grand a user privileges like this

```
GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE TO "user";
```

you can also grand the `ADMIN OPTION` like this

```
GRANT UPDATE ANY TABLE TO "user" WITH ADMIN OPTION;
```

Also you can grand privilages to specific role/users to specific tables :

```
GRANT SELECT ON "table_name" TO "user_or_role";
```

> The following statement grants the SELECT, INSERT, and DELETE object privileges for all columns of the emp table to the users jfee and tsmith:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON "table" TO "user1", "user2";
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm for managing user privileges

Comment: i try to test it but it doesn't has any result

Comment: i wirte GRAND and REVOKE like above Statement but appears anything

Comment: what command exactly and where do you write it? in what tool? do you commit?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo that you don't have semi-co0lons on the end?

What output do you get when you run your statements?

Answer (score 0):

Did you issue the GRANT and then the REVOKE together?  GRANT gives and REVOKE takes away so issuing them together means that nothing will be done.  Just issue the GRANT statement to give access

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON schema.table1 TO username;
```

will allow USERNAME to insert and update rows in TABLE1 in SCHEMA.

```
REVOKE INSERT, UPDATE ON schema.table1 FROM username;
```

will remove the grants that allowed USERNAME to insert and update rows in TABLE1 in SCHEMA if you granted them (otherwise it will tell you that you did not grant them).